# Adding custom fonts to drupal CKEDITOR

Tags: php, drupal, ckeditor

I have fonts I need to add to the Drupal editor. I've added the `@font-face` to my stylesheet
and then added the fonts to `CKEDITOR.config.font_names`.

It works but I'm editing a drupel core  file (`plugin.js`) which is bad for many reasons.
I wanna do it from my theme. How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Here are few steps mentioned in this article.

- Go to admin/config/content/ckeditor.
- Click on edit against the profile for which you need the fonts .
- Click on Advanced Options.
- Inside the Custom Javascript configuration box, add the fonts you want
- After that , you have to tell the ck editor , where are your fonts.

https://www.zyxware.com/articles/3692/drupal-how-to-add-fonts-in-ck-editor

Answer (score 0):

Here are the instructions for Drupal 8/9.

1. Put font files into your theme/module's directory.
2. Define new font faces. I would recommend doing it in a separate file e.g `fonts.css`.

```
 @font-face {
      font-family: "Font name";
      src: url("../fonts/fontfile.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/fontfile.woff") format("woff");
    }
```

3. Add a library or edit an existing one in your `libraries.info` file.

   ```
   ckeditor_adjustments:
     version: 1.x
     css:
       theme:
         css/fonts.css: {}
   ```
4. Attach library:

   ```
   function mymodule_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {
     $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'mymodule/ckeditor_adjustments';
   }
   ```
5. Go to edit your text format where "Font-family" button is enabled and add new font families under "Font settings" tab and add your font families.